# Dynamic comparison with ef based on a property string name

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

For my application i pass a 'Filter' object to my backend which has a property name and a property value.

I found the following code on the internet to do a dynamic Contains with ef

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Contains<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
        {
            var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
            var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
            var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
            var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
            var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

            var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp);

            var expcall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new[] {typeof(T)}, queryable.Expression,Expression.Quote(expression));

            return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expcall);
        }
```

Which i call like this:

```
query = query.Contains(filter.Property, (string)filter.Value);
```

Now i'm trying to find the same for a comparison to do this:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Status == filter.Value);
```

x.Status is an enum so

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Status.Equals(filter.Value));
```

throws

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Even when i cast it to an int.

So i need to do '==' instead of equals but i don't know how to build a method like the Contains one without a method name like Contains or Equals

What i want, something like this:

```
query = query.IsTheSame(filter.Property, (Status)filter.Value);
```

Comment: Please include the code that is not working and explain how you know it is not working (compiler error? runtime exception? wrong result? …?)

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator checks for exact match and in case you are using equivalent, but different objects, the `==` operator between them would be false. `Equals` will be true in case of similar but different objects. So I guess the solution would be

```
query = query.Where(x => (x.Status != null) && (x.Status.Equals(val)));
```

Answer (score 0):

> So i need to do '==' instead of equals but i don't know how to build a method like the Contains one without a method name like Contains or Equals

This actually is even easier thanks to the [`Expression.Equal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352749(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Here is a sample implementation (with bonus handling the nested property/fields):

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string memberPath, object value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    var member = memberPath.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant(value)),
        parameter);
    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

Which you call like this:

```
query = query.WhereEquals(filter.Property, filter.Value);
```